# Can covering be done on two elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, boolean-algebra

The covering rule is: $$B \bullet (B+C) = B$$ and $$B+(B \bullet C)=B$$ So does it follow from this rule that: $$B \bullet A \bullet \bar{C} + B \bullet D \bullet\bar{F} = B \bullet (A\bullet\bar{C}+D\bullet\bar{F}) = B? $$
Or does the covering rule apply only to terms with one variable?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an application of your rule unless $A\cdot \overline{C} = B$.

Comment: Also what is this structure? A ring?

Comment: @JonnyLomond it's boolean algebra, or boolean ring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the equation at the end of your post is not valid. For example, if $A = D = \bot$ and $B\neq \bot$ ($\bot$, also denoted $0$ or $\emptyset$, is the bottom element of the boolean algebra), then $B\cdot A \cdot \bar{C} + B \cdot D \cdot \bar{F} = \bot + \bot = \bot$.

The first equality, $B\cdot A \cdot \bar{C} + B \cdot D \cdot \bar{F} = B\cdot (A\cdot \bar{C} + D \cdot \bar{F})$ is valid by distributivity. But there's no $B$ inside the parentheses, so there's no way to apply the covering rule at this point.

As for your question about terms with one variable, here's an example where you *can* apply the covering rule: $(x+y)\cdot (x+y+z\cdot w+z\cdot x) = x+y$. We can take $B = x+y$ and $C = z\cdot w+z\cdot x$ in the statement of the covering rule.